# C++ I can't get templates to work in a linked list for some reason, I bet is a simple error but I just don't get it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, linked-list

I have to make a linked list that works with a template so that it can get any type of data in. That part seems simple enough, but for some reason I have twitched my code in all possible ways and my understanding of the whole template thing just doesn't seem to be enough.

"LinkedList.h"

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H
using namespace std;

template <class N>
class list{
private:

template <class N>
struct node{

N data;
node* next;

};  
    node<N>* head;
    node<N>* curr;
    node<N>* temp;
    node<N>* tail;

public:
    list();
    void AddNode(N addData);
    void DeleteNode(N delData);
    void PrintList();

};

template <class N>
list<N>::list(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

}

template <class N>
void list<N>::AddNode(N addData){
    node<N>* n = new node;
    n->next=NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if (head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}

template <class N>
void list<N>::DeleteNode(N delData){
    node<N>* delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL && curr->data != delData) {
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL){
        cout << delData << " Was not in the list." << endl;
        delete delPtr;
    }
    else {
        delPtr = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        temp->next = curr;
        if (delPtr == head){
            head = head->next;
            temp = NULL;
        } 
        delete delPtr;
        cout << "The value " << delData << " was deleted." << endl;
    }

}

template <class N>
void list<N>::PrintList(){
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

#endif
```

and the main is just to test if the functions actually work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "LinkedList.h"


int main(){
    list<int> a;
    a.AddNode(3);


    a.PrintList();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

But they don't, I get 17 errors and all of them are just syntax errors that make no sense, like `; missing before < in line 1` and so.
Please can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I know it has to be something simple that I can't see because I'm new at this, but it's so frustrating!

Comment: When you get a bunch of errors similar to what you say (can you please include the actual errors? copy-pasted as text?) , always look at the *first* error. Go to the line indicated by that error, does it look like there is a problem on that line? No? Then go to the *previous* (non-empty, no-comment) line (which isn't reported in the error messages) and look what you do there. If the previous line is an `#include` then you check the end of the header file being included.

Comment: In `AddNode` the line `node<N>* n = new node;` is using `node<N>` in one place but just `node` in another place.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code and I only get a "shadowed template parameter" that can be solved by moving your node declaration outside the linked list declaration. Then at list::AddNode(N) you have to correct your declaration of n.

I was be able to compile it, but I did not test your code in depth.

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H
using namespace std;

template <class N>
struct node{

N data;
node* next;

};

template <class N>
class list{
private:


    node<N>* head;
    node<N>* curr;
    node<N>* temp;
    node<N>* tail;

public:
    list();
    void AddNode(N addData);
    void DeleteNode(N delData);
    void PrintList();

};

template <class N>
list<N>::list(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

}

template <class N>
void list<N>::AddNode(N addData){
  node<N>* n = new node<N>; // previously: node<N>* n = new node;
    n->next=NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if (head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}

template <class N>
void list<N>::DeleteNode(N delData){
    node<N>* delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL && curr->data != delData) {
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL){
        cout << delData << " Was not in the list." << endl;
        delete delPtr;
    }
    else {
        delPtr = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        temp->next = curr;
        if (delPtr == head){
            head = head->next;
            temp = NULL;
        } 
        delete delPtr;
        cout << "The value " << delData << " was deleted." << endl;
    }

}

template <class N>
void list<N>::PrintList(){
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

#endif
```

Then at main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "ll.hpp"


int main(){
    list<int> a;
    a.AddNode(3);
    a.AddNode(5);
    a.AddNode(1);
    a.PrintList();
    a.DeleteNode(4);
    a.PrintList();
    a.AddNode(10);
    a.DeleteNode(3);
    a.PrintList();

    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

With an output of

```
3
5
1
4 Was not in the list.
3
5
1
The value 3 was deleted.
5
1
10
```